# Launch AccessibilitySettings with XML settings in android

Tags: java, android, xml, accessibility, android-preferences

I want to launch the Accessibility Settings view and it says that it dosen't exist...

This is a preference list:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <header
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
        android:summary="Must be enabled to work."
        android:title="Accessibility State" >
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
            android:targetClass="com.android.settings.AccessibilitySettings"
            android:targetPackage="com.android.settings" />
    </header>

</preference-headers>
```

And it says error:

> E/AndroidRuntime(4510): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
>   Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.AccessibilitySettings};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

¿Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

The action you're looking for is defined by [Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS) as "android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS". You won't need to define a target class or package.

```
<intent android:action="android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: **It dosent work:**

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {android.settings/android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? `

**Another try:**

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
 `

Comment: Are you specifying a target class and package in your Intent tag? All you need is an action, as in the example.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when a call to `startActivity(Intent)` or one of its variants fails because an Activity can not be found to execute the given Intent.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to know why. I need to run the view com.android.settings.AccessibilitySettings from a configuration view...